# Torch - Using optim package with CNN

Tags: lua, neural-network, conv-neural-network, torch, training-data

I am trying to train a CNN using `optim` package. I am using [this code](https://github.com/syamprasadkr/learning_torch/blob/master/train.lua), obtained from a [video tutorial](https://youtu.be/kcOJEplX7i0?list=PLLHTzKZzVU9ebuL6DCclzI54MrPNFGqbW) (see around 24:01), as a reference. This particular example uses a normal neural network. I also used [this reference](https://github.com/soumith/cvpr2015/blob/master/Deep%20Learning%20with%20Torch.ipynb).

My code for the CNN can be found [here](https://github.com/syamprasadkr/learning_torch/blob/master/cnn_1.lua). The problem is that if the input `X` is not a single image, I get an error:

```
In 14 module of nn.Sequential:
/home/ubuntu/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/Linear.lua:57: size mismatch at /tmp/luarocks_cutorch-scm-1-1695/cutorch/lib/THC/generic/THCTensorMathBlas.cu:52
```

When I don't use GPU, the error becomes more clear:

```
size mismatch, [1024 x 2048], [409600]
```

For convenience, I have copied my complete model:

```
-- Model begins
local model = nn.Sequential()
model:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(1, 64, 3, 3))
model:add(nn.ReLU())
model:add(nn.SpatialMaxPooling(2, 2, 2, 2))

model:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(64, 128, 3, 3))
model:add(nn.ReLU())
model:add(nn.SpatialMaxPooling(2, 2, 2, 2))

model:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(128, 256, 3, 3))
model:add(nn.ReLU())
model:add(nn.SpatialMaxPooling(2, 2, 2, 2))

model:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(256, 512, 3, 3))
model:add(nn.ReLU())
model:add(nn.SpatialMaxPooling(2, 2, 2, 2))

model:add(nn.View(-1))
model:add(nn.Linear(2048, 1024))
model:add(nn.ReLU())
model:add(nn.Linear(1024, 5))
model:add(nn.LogSoftMax())
-- Model ends
```

1) Is it right to use `nn.View(-1)`?

2) I understand that the input to the first `Linear` layer is not `2048` when the input `X` has more than one image. But how does `optim.sgd` work properly with the entire training set used as input (`X`), in the case of the normal neural network given in first reference?

3) What would be the best way to use `optim.sgd` (or preferably `optim.adam`) in this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module `nn.View` has not been written properly. This layer should be written as:
`nn.View(−1, out_channels * out_height * out_width)`. In the above case, it would be 
`nn.View(-1, 2048)`. **Source**: See the comments section of [this](https://youtu.be/kcOJEplX7i0?list=PLLHTzKZzVU9ebuL6DCclzI54MrPNFGqbW).